# Meaning of __unwind in IDA pro?

Tags: c, ida

In IDA some functions have the `__unwind` keyword, usually followed by the name of a compiler-generated function like `__C_specific_handler` or `__GSHandlerCheck`. What does `__unwind` mean and what relevance do the compiler generated functions have?